# Me sale esta error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLInputElement.calcularMontos (main.js:63)

Tags: javascript

Nesecito que laguien me ayude con este error por que no soy muy bueno con JavaScript, muchas gracias.
Para aclarar no esta todo el codigo por que si no no me deja publicarlo ya que me dice que es demaciado codigo.
`
calcular.addEventListener('click', calcularMontos);

```
    function calcularMontos(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (regalo.value === '') {
            alert("Debes elegir un regalo");
            regalo.focus();
        } else {
            var boletosDia = parseInt(pase_dia.value, 10) || 0,
                boletos2Dias = parseInt(pase_dosdias.value, 10) || 0,
                boletoCompleto = parseInt(pase_completo.value, 10) || 0,
                cantCamisas = parseInt(camisas.value, 10) || 0,
                cantEtiquetas = parseInt(etiquetas.value, 10) || 0;


            var totalPagar = (boletosDia * 30) + (boletos2Dias * 45) + (boletoCompleto * 50) + ((cantCamisas * 10) * .93) + (cantEtiquetas * 2);

            var listadoProductos = [];

            if (boletosDia >= 1) {
                listadoProductos.push(boletosDia + ' Pases por dia');
            }
            if (boletos2Dias >= 1) {
                listadoProductos.push(boletos2Dias + ' Pases por dos dias');
            }
            if (boletoCompleto >= 1) {
                listadoProductos.push(boletoCompleto + ' Pases completos');
            }
            if (cantCamisas >= 1) {
                listadoProductos.push(cantCamisas + ' Camisas');
            }
            if (cantEtiquetas >= 1) {
                listadoProductos.push(cantEtiquetas + ' Etiquetas');
            }

            var lista_productos = document.querySelector('lista_productos');

            lista_productos.innerHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < listadoProductos.length; i++) {
                lista_productos.innerHTML += listadoProductos[i] + '<br/>';
            }`
```

Comment: var lista_productos = document.querySelector('lista_productos'); te esta dando null si te estas referiendo a 1 objeto por ID debes usar document.getElementByID("lista_productos").

Comment: Me dice que es mucho codigo si lo pongo

Comment: @toto ya lo intente pero me da el eeroer en el innerHTML

Comment: @toto no es del todo cierto lo que mencionas, ese método si le funciona siempre y cuando si es un id entonces el OP lo indique con el símbolo de # al inicio

Comment: @BetaM    <input id="calcular" type="submit" class="boton" value="Calcular">
                  </div>
                 <!--extras-->
                 <div class="total">
                        <p>Resumen</p>
                        <div id="lista-productos">
                     </div>
                  <p>Total:</p>
                <div id="suma-total">  </div>
              <input id="btnRegistro" type="submit" class="boton" value="Pagar">
                   </div>
                  <!--.total-->
                </div>
         <!--.caja-->
       </div>
     <!--.resumen-->

Comment: Solo escribelo así y te debe funcionar: **`var lista_productos = document.querySelector('#lista_productos');`**